# How do I force a function to be called immediately in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, memoization

This is my code:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize
import Debug.Trace

foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo a = memoFix fooMemo where 
    fooMemo f x = a + (trace (show x) cont) where
        cont = if x == 0 then 0 else x + f (x - 1)

main = do
    print $ foo 0 5
    print $ foo 0 5
    print $ foo 0 5
```

I expected it to print:

```
3
2
1
0
6
6
6
```

But, instead, it prints this:

```
3
2
1
0
6
3
2
1
0
6
3
2
1
0
6
```

In other words, the function is not memoized as I expected it to be. This is probably because each time "foo 0" is called, a new memo-table is created for "foo". How can I force GHC to evaluate "memoFix fooMemo" only once, so that it doesn't create more than one memotable?

Comment: What package is `Data.Function.Memoize` from?

Comment: @DanielWagner [memoize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize)

Comment: FWIW, I see a very different behavior with your code than what you report. I think perhaps your actual code is using `3` as the last argument rather than `5`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the memotable is created for *each* parameter value, `foo 0` etc., not for the whole of `foo`.  And then those memotables are not shared from one invocation of `foo` to the next.  The solution is to make sure to *also* memoize the whole of `foo`:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize
import Debug.Trace

foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo = memoize foo1 where
    foo1 a = memoFix fooMemo where 
        fooMemo f x = a + (trace (show x) cont) where
            cont = if x == 0 then 0 else x + f (x - 1)

main = do
    print $ foo 0 5
    print $ foo 0 5
    print $ foo 0 5
```

BTW I find the following way of writing it easier than using `memoFix`:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo = memoize2 $ \a x ->
    let cont = if x == 0 then 0 else x + foo a (x - 1)
    in a + (trace (show x) cont)
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
main = let f = foo 0 in do
    print $ f 5
    print $ f 5
    print $ f 5
```